# getopt always returning -1 / getopt not doing anything

Tags: c, unix, getopt

I am trying to parse command line arguments using getopt(). Below is my code. getopt() is always returning -1 no matter what arguments I pass when running the program.

For example:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ ./test f
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void usage (char * progname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage Instructions Here ...\n");
    exit(-1);
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int opt;

    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "?hf:")) != -1) {
        switch(opt) {
            case '?':
            case 'h':
                usage(argv[0]);
                break;
            case 'f':
                {
                    FILE *fp;
                    char *filename = strdup(optarg);

                    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
                        usage(argv[0]);
                    } 
                }
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Error - No such opt, '%c'\n", opt);
                usage(argv[0]);
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: So.. what are the some example of how you are running it?

Comment: Options should start with `-` or `--`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually passing an option here:

```
$ ./test f
```

Options are expected to start with a `-` character.  `f` does not, so it is not considered an option.  If you call it like this:

```
$ ./test -f
```

You'll get this:

```
./test: option requires an argument -- 'f'
Usage Instructions Here ...
```

Also, the `?` character has special meaning to `getopt`.  It is returned when an unknown option is found, with a copy of the invalid option stored in `optopt`.  So you probably don't want to use `?` in your option string.

Comment: So, in relation to `?` and `optopt`, I should remove `case '?':` and I should also change `fprintf(stderr, "Error - No such opt, '%c'\n", opt); ` to `fprintf(stderr, "Error - No such opt, '%c'\n", optopt);`

Comment: @Smaointe Yes, remove the existing `case '?':`, change the `default` case to `case '?':`, and print `optopt` in that case.